# Random Image Script Working but Want to Avoid Duplicates

Tags: images, get-posts

I'm using the following to display random images:

```
<?php $new_query = new WP_Query('&showposts=24'); ?>
         <?php while ($new_query->have_posts()) : $new_query->the_post(); ?>
         <?php $args = array (
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'numberposts' => 1,
            'orderby' => rand,
            'status' => 'publish',
            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
            'parent' => $post->ID
         ); ?>
         <?php $attachments = get_posts($args);
            if ($attachments) {
                foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
                    echo '<li>';
                    echo wp_get_attachment_link($attachment->ID, 'thumbnail', true, '');
                    echo '</li>';
                }
            };

            endwhile;
```

But I'm trying to avoid duplicates. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you getting the duplicates, do you mean the same looking image with a diff file name?

Comment: Wyck I seem to be getting the same image more than once, which makes sense I guess due to 'numberposts' being set to rand, which I want, but I don't want the same image twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use `post__not_in` because you are using `'orderby' => rand,`.

You will need to throw the post or attachment ID ( I suppose you can also use something else) into and array in the first loop and use that array in as a second query parameter, in essence you are doing 2 loops.

I don't have to ability to test the actual code but the logic would be along the lines of;

```
    $remove_duplicates = array(); //create an array to hold post id's (or whatever you use)

    $new_query = new WP_Query('&showposts=24&orderby=rand'); //add your other queries params here

    while ($new_query->have_posts()) : $new_query->the_post(); // start first loop

    $remove_duplicates[] = $post->ID ?>  // throw duplicate post Id's into an array

    endwhile;  // end first loop

    // start second loop for your output using the array

      $args=array(
                 'numberposts' => 1,
                 'orderby' => rand,
                 'status' => 'publish',
                 'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                 'parent' => $post->ID
                 'post__not_in'=> $remove_duplicates ); // this is the important part to remove the duplicates.

      // rest of your output.
```

Sorry I was unable to test this, if it doesn't work , another option would be to just use a native PHP function like `array_unique` to remove the duplicates in the array before output.